# mouse pad freezes

Tags: mouse

I have an acer aspire running net book remix 11.10. the mouse pad freezes up completely and I must use an external mouse. if I reboot the computer the mouse pad will work again. i seem to have this problem happen in  the middle of either using firefox or a few time while using thunderbird. anyone else having this problem. an external mouse works but scrolling is choppy or it scrolls part of the way down a page and then jumps to the top again. I don't recall having this problem after upgrading to 11.10 so I think it is related to an update. my Linux skills are limited.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this same problem on my Sony Vaio using my ALPS GlidePoint mousepad.

I can't currently offer a permanent solution, but in my case at least, I've determined that the property 'Synaptics Off' is being switched to 1 (true), and when I change it back to 0 (false) my mousepad works again.

You can access and change the properties through the terminal (ctrl+alt+t). Here is an example of what I do:

`xinput list`

I look for the name of my mousepad and note it's displayed ID. For this example, id=10
Then:

`xinput set-prop 10 'Synaptics Off' 0`

After this, my mousepad works again. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to open a terminal via keyboard-shortcut 
use this command to re-enable your trackpad: `synclient touchpadOff=1` or `synclient touchpadOff=0`

Please let us know if it worked for you!!